# Show that the squared of a concave function is lower than...

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $x \in (0,1)$ and $F(x) \in (0,1)$. Suppose $F(0)=0$ and $F(1)=1$, and suppose $F(x)$ is continuous and strictly concave. Show that:

$F(x)^2 < F(xF(x))$

I have a feeling that it is like this. Also, I have not been able to find a single counter-example. However I have hard times seeing how to prove that. Any tips?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Looks like the assumption $F(1)=1$ is superfluous.

Comment: @Adren As is the assumption that $x\in (0, 1)$. We only need that $\mathrm{im}(F)\subseteq [0, 1]$ and that $F(0) = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider that by the concavity of $F$, for $x_1, x_2\in [0, 1]$ and $\lambda\in (0, 1)$, $$F(\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2) > \lambda F(x_1)+(1-\lambda)F(x_2)$$ In this case, let $\lambda = F(x)\in (0, 1)$, let $x_1 = x\in [0, 1]$, and let $x_2 = 0$. Then, $$F(x\cdot F(x)) > F(x)\cdot F(x) = F(x)^2$$

Comment: Thanks Michael Lee and @Adren, it was really helpful. Now I am trying to generalize this result and see if it holds for when $F$ is strictly concave only in a subset of $x$. Do you think it can be done? The problem would be the following:
Suppose $F(x)\in[0,1]$ and $x\in[0,1]$. Suppose $F(0)=0$ and $F(1)=1$, and suppose that $F(x)$ is continuous and strictly concave when $x\in[F(x^*)x^*,x^*]$. Show that:
$F(x^*)^2<F(F(x^*)x^*)$
There might be some superfluous assumptions, but these all assumptions are the ones I can make.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I have posted the new question here:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2189848/show-that-fx%E2%88%972ffx%E2%88%97x%E2%88%97-when-f-in0-1-is-strictly-concave-for-x-in
Thank you!