# Show that $F(x^∗)^2<F(F(x^∗)x^∗)$ when $F\in[0,1]$ is strictly concave for $x\in[F(x^*)x^*,X]$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $F(x)∈[0,1]$ and $x∈[0,X]$. Suppose $F(0)=0$ and $F(X)=1$, and suppose that $F(x)$ is continuous and strictly concave for $x∈[F(x^∗)x^∗,X]$. Show that:

$F(x^∗)^2<F(x^*F(x^∗))$

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If it helps, this is the proof I was given to the same problem when assuming F concave for any x: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2188525/show-that-the-squared-of-a-concave-function-is-lower-than

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The opposite inequality can hold. Consider $X=1,\,x^*=\frac34,\,F(x^*)=\frac 23,\,F(\frac 12)=0$, and interpolate to make $F$ strictly concave in $[\frac12,\frac34]$. Then $F(x^*)^2=\frac49>0=F(x^*F(x^*))$.